# Facebook Login is opening in Facebook Native app not in safari browser on iphone device with ios 6.0

Tags: iphone, facebook

Hello I am using FBSession to open login view it opens Safari for login in iOS5.0 and ios 6.0 Simulator but in ios 6.0 iPhone it is opening Facebook APP not safari.Please tell me what is reason and how can I solve it?Here is my code for Facebook login.

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState state,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                                             [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                 state:state
                                                                 error:error];
                                         }];
}

/*
 * Callback for session changes.
 */
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            if (!error) {
                // We have a valid session
                NSLog(@"User session found");

                if ([[IntegrationManager sharedInstance] facebookDidLogin:nil]) {
                    [self.window.rootViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                };

            }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:NSLog(@"Fbsession close");
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:FBSessionStateChangedNotification
     object:session];

    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                  message:error.localizedDescription
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the user convenience the facebook app is started instead of the opening a website. It is done so the user does not have to login in again, it is also known as single sign on.

If you are using the Facebook iOS SDK there is nothing you can do about or should do about it.

Comment: No, it should also work on iOS 5 and 4. Als long as the Facebook app is installed. In iOS 6 you can use the native Facebook support which will just popup the question to the users if they allow your app access to there facebook account.